# How can I pick an old Dexter brass privacy door handle with a sliding latch?

Tags: hardware, door, privacy

The lock is a couple of tabs that protrude from the door handle ring(part behind knob that is flush against door). You slide the tabs parallel to the floor to lock and unlock.
On the knob on the other side of the door there is a hole in the ring(see picture). Presumably to put in some kind of key to unlock it. You can't lock yourself out as handle needs to be unlocked in order to open door. But I have small children and wanted to know how to pick this type of lock in case they accidentally lock themselves inside.
Tried using bobby pins and thin drill bits in the hole to unlock, but no luck.

[image: Doorlock]

Answer (score 1):

Most knob sets with that hole on the outside are intended to be unlocked with a small flat-blade screwdriver.  Some come with a "key" that is just exactly, made from bent heavy wire.

Try shining a light into the hole, you should see a slot inside; put a small screwdriver into the slot, and turn one way or the other.  Done!